# Is there a tool for calculating the number of function points in a C# program?

Tags: c#, function-points

Is there a tool for calculating the number of function points in a C# program?

If there is nothing that measures the number of function points, how about a tool that measures something similar?

Comment: Are you referring to function points as in function point analysis? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_point

Comment: [Metrics like that usually cause more harm than good.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/11/16/10091537.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

IIRC this is one of the various metrics NDepend covers, but it's been awhile since I've used it.

http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#Metrics

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool for calculating micro function points, called Project Code Meter:

http://www.projectcodemeter.com